# Emacs starts utterly maximized -- can't see Dash or System Tray

Tags: 22.04, gui, unity-dash, emacs, system-tray

In my Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, I inadvertently hit some combination of keystrokes, and now whenever I start Emacs it wholly maximizes itself --- to such a degree that the Dash bar and the System Tray are no longer visible.  See the screenshot below... note that this is a *full screenshot*, not just a picture of the Emacs window alone; no part of the standard Ubuntu interface components are visible, but I want them back!  (if I close Emacs everything is visible again... but it used to work with that program, too!)

EDIT 1: I can't resize the window with the mouse because the program's window utterly takes up the entire window - there is not a single pixel left, and trying to click in the extreme corners is just interpreted as clicking inside the application window.

[image: Emacs taking up entire screen; no Dash or Tray visible]

Answer (score 1):

The solution lay in Emacs, not in Ubuntu.  As described in [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/how-to-toggle-fullscreen-in-emacs-gui-mode-full-screen-option-is-greyed-out-i?newreg=24904f6ed2be4e86b4616a8b3b94c1ce), in Emacs I just needed to run `toggle-frame-fullscreen` .  (How this mode was turned on in the first place is anyone's guess.)

Answer (score 0):

Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and hit <kbd>Space</kbd>
*(let go of Alt)*
then select Unmaximize from the menu.

If that options isn't there, then either your window should be possible to resize; i.e. by grabbing a corner with the left mouse button... OR the software was written (set up) to NOT ALLOW that.

*If the last; I'd complain with the creator or even stop using the software.*

Comment: I did try that, but 'Unmaximize' isn't an option. The options are: Take Screenshot; Hide; (Maximize) [grayed out], (Move) [grayed out], (Resize) [grayed out], Move Titlebar Onscreen, Always on Top, Always on Visible Workspace, Move to Workspace Right, and Close.

Comment: ... added text above.

Comment: Thanks for the edit - but my software was resizeable until earlier today, when some mysterious combination of keystrokes seems to have changed its properties.  I can't resize the window with the mouse because the program's window utterly takes up the entire window - there is not a single pixel left, and trying to click in the extreme corners is just interpreted as clicking inside the application window.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572950/preserve-window-layout-in-emacs - maybe?